# Microsoft edge border-radius bugs

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9, microsoft-edge

In IE(>9) and Microsoft Edge,border-radius have a bugs when border-width is very wide.

```css
.number {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    left: -3px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    
    background: #ff7322;
    border-radius: 50px;
    border: 8px solid #f0f0f0;
    
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<span class="number">1.1</span>
```

Comment: What is your [question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Comment: What bug are you referring to, exactly? Your snippet does not appear to demonstrate anything out of the ordinary in any of those browsers.

Comment: @BoltClock its common IE problem ... the Questions is kind of duplicated actually

Comment: @BoltClock I can not put img in this question,sorry.But,if you read this by IE,you can get this problem

Comment: I edit your Question and add some photos ... to make the problem clear because its general in chrome ... please approve the changes or add the photos your self for documentation reasons .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its bug it IE

There is a workaround for these issues: element can be replaced with two nested elements, where the inner element has the desired background color as its background while the outer element’s background color is equal to the desired border color, and the outer element has padding equal to the desired border width.

**HTML**

```
 <div class="ok"><div>…</div></div>
```

**CSS**

```
    .ok {
        background: #000; /* Border color */
        border-radius: 100px;
        padding: 70px; /* Border width */
    }

    .ok > DIV {
        background: #fff; /* Background color */
        border-radius: 30px; /* Radius of outer element minus border  width */
        height: 60px; /* For illustration purposes */
    }
```

Example and source : 
http://tanalin.com/_experimentz/demos/blog/2011/border-radius-rendering/

Comment: @adwerrd did this help you please make the answer and accepted so others will benefit form me and the Question will mark as solved

Comment: yes,your answer is valid,I know that this method can solve this problem

Comment: actually I think its matter of time only before Microsoft solve the problem in IE or solve IE it self be remove it for good .

Comment: I think so.But I think that the problem should't show in Microsoft Edge